# What function could an “Asp.Net Core hosted” Blazor WebAssembly server site provide if my site will use a web api for back-end work instead?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-webassembly

If I tick the “Asp.Net Core hosted” checkbox in Visual Studio when creating a Blazor WebAssembly project I get a back-end for my site, a “MySite.Server” project appears. But if my site is going to call a web api for data etc., something it can easily do in the “MySite.Client” project instead, then what use is the MySite.Server project to me?

Calling a web api means I have to manage CORS and MySite.Server will not need this as client and server are the same site, but other than that I can’t think of any reasons to choose it over a regular .Net web api project.

Comment: But do you see any reasons to choose a regular .Net web api project over a Hosting one?

Comment: A web api decouples the client site from the api services, which enables reusability for other clients and future front-end upgrades

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is with security...

If MySite.Server talks to the web api, this all happens on the server and the web api doesn’t have to be exposed to the Internet.

If MySite.Server needs access to an authentication server (id / token provider), again, this happens on the server and the authentication server doesn’t have to be exposed to the Internet.

But if MySite.Client talks to the web api or an authentication server then it must be available on the Internet and any secrets to connect to these would be available too.

Unlike MySite.Client, MySite.Server is not downloaded to the browser, and so the use of any web apis, authentication server, secrets, databases connections, etc. all remain part of the back-end (like a traditional MVC application) and are secure.